# What's the best way to find cheap flight tickets from any place from a set of places to any place in another set of places?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, flight-search-engines

For example, how do I find the cheapest tickets from any place in India to any place in either of England, Germany, Netherlands, Spain. Hope the questions makes sense?